# Referencia Cruzada SQL SERVER por meses

Tags: sql-server

tengo esta Consulta de Referencia Cruzada que me totalliza las unidades por mes y año y funciona perfectamente, lo que quisiera es poder sumar todos los meses en la misma Fila como Total, poder sumar [1],[2],[3] .... Al final de la fila. Muchas gracias por adelantado

```
select anio, [1] Ene, [2] Feb, [3] Mar, [4] Abr, [5] May, [6] Jun,
             [7] Jul, [8] Ago, [9] Sep, [10] Oct, [11] Nov, [12] Dic, [13] Total
from (
    -- select inicial, a pivotar. Podría ser una tabla
    select  year(O.Fecha) as anio, month(O.Fecha) as Mes,
            D.Unitats as Cantidad
    from [Linpediv] D inner join Cabpediv O on D.Pedido = O.PEDIDO
    where O.Fecha between '20000101' and '20171231'
) V PIVOT ( sum(Cantidad) FOR Mes IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],
        [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13]) ) as PT
```

Answer (score 2):

Por empezar, faltan los `group by`. La consulta básica sería esta:

```
select  year(O.Fecha) as anio,
        month(O.Fecha) as Mes,
        SUM(D.Unitats) as Cantidad
        from [Linpediv] D 
        inner join Cabpediv O 
             on D.Pedido = O.PEDIDO
        where O.Fecha between '20000101' and '20171231'
        group by year(O.Fecha),month(O.Fecha)
```

Ahora bien, una posibilidad es agregarle a esta misma consulta la sumatoria total por año para que después el `PIVOT` lo lea como la columna 13:

```
select  year(O.Fecha) as anio,
        month(O.Fecha) as Mes,
        SUM(D.Unitats) as Cantidad
        from [Linpediv] D 
        inner join Cabpediv O 
             on D.Pedido = O.PEDIDO
        where O.Fecha between '20000101' and '20171231'
        group by year(O.Fecha),month(O.Fecha)

 union

 select year(O.Fecha) as anio,
        13 as Mes,
        SUM(D.Unitats) as Cantidad
        from [Linpediv] D 
        inner join Cabpediv O 
             on D.Pedido = O.PEDIDO
        where O.Fecha between '20000101' and '20171231'
        group by year(O.Fecha)
```

La otra posibilidad mas simple, es sumar las 12 columnas en el select final:

```
select anio, [1] Ene, [2] Feb, [3] Mar, [4] Abr, [5] May, [6] Jun,
             [7] Jul, [8] Ago, [9] Sep, [10] Oct, [11] Nov, [12] Dic, 
             [1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12] Total
```